# How to zip List of lists

Tags: scala

I've got

```
val l List[List[Int]] = List(List(0,0,0),List(1,1,1))
```

and I want to get it zipped. Is there any succinct way to do it instead of accessing each element of main list by index and zip it together with `zip` command?

Comment: Could you show us the output you're expecting?

Comment: What if there are more than 22 elements in the list (you can only have up to 22 elements in a tuple)? What if there is only one (or none at all)?  What if lists have different lengths? Or do you mean by "zip" something completely different than what the rest of us thinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, under the assumption that the outer list has exacly two inner lists.

```
List(List(0,0,0), List(1, 1, 1)) match {
  case l1 :: l2 :: Nil => l1 zip l2
  case x => ??? // up to you
}
```

In order to take into account the possibility of failure, you can wrap the result into an `Option`.

```
val x = List(List(0,0,0), List(1, 1, 1))
val res: Option[List[Int]] = x match {
  case l1 :: l2 :: Nil => Some(l1 zip l2)
  case x => None
}
```